# Fluent nhibernate gets slow on sql express compared to MS Access

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, ms-access-2010, sql-server-express

I have a windows application running with fluent nHibernate and data stored on an MS Access database on a local server.

I have now transferred the data to an SQL Express database, on the same server and running the same code on this server, but now the respond time has doubled compared to the response time of the access database.

I know I can check my queries and try to use lazyload, but the problem is not that the program is working slow, the respond time is fine on the Access Database, but not on the SQL Express Database.

Any bids to why the respond time doubles on an SQL Express compared to an Access Database?

Comment: Did you have the same indexes? Did you try the same code under 10 users concurrent load? Did you try to move the database location on a network path?

Comment: I just imported the MS Access DB into the SQL Express DB, so I assume indexes are the same. I have only tested it on my machine, so 1 user. Yes I tried to move the Acces Database to a different location on the server. Still same result

Comment: Don't assume, check.

Comment: Everything is the same. Maybe it is worth mentioning, that when I just extract data on one object, with no nHIbernate relations, the query is faster than on the Acces Database. As soon as I put a one-to-many relationship into the query, the response time is doubled

Answer (score 0):

That's by "design" or rather due to the physical layout.

Access *is* very fast for not so large tables.

What you gain with SQL Server is added flexibility (connection, hosting, scalability, T-SQL, management, better multiuser support, etc.), including all the features of a self-contained database engine - compared to a file based engine as JET/ACE of Access is.

Also, the speed you experience now will probably remain stable.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I just find it funny, that with a query on one table it works far better than access, but as soon as I make 1 relation between 2 objects, the speed is extremely slow. If this is by design, why do anyone use ORMs?

Comment: Your ORM is responsible for the final SQL generated. It may be optimised for Access/JET but not for SQL Server. I'm no expert in SQL Server, but I believe you can set up logging for you to study the commands sent to the engine. That might tell you why.